# constructor initialisation order when Base constructor depends on reference from Derived

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a base class which writes objects to a `std::ostream` with buffering. I want to call this with

```cpp
  Obj obj;
  flat_file_stream_writer<Obj> writer(std::cout);
  writer.write(obj);
  writer.flush();
```

but also with

```cpp
  Obj obj;
  flat_file_writer<Obj> writer("filename.bin");
  writer.write(obj);
  writer.flush();
```

The latter call must establish a `std::ofstream` instance, and hold that for the duration of writing, and can then call the former version.

I thought simple non-virtual inheritance would be fine here. But I have constructor initialization order issues.

```
warning: field 'ofstream_' will be initialized after base
      'flat_file_stream_writer<hibp::pawned_pw>' [-Wreorder-ctor]
```

Because the base class depends on a *reference* to the object held by the *derived* this seems like chicken and egg and can't be solved?

Is inheritance just the wrong abstraction here? A clean alternative?

```cpp
template <typename ValueType>
class flat_file_stream_writer {

  public:
    explicit flat_file_stream_writer(std::ostream& os, std::size_t buf_size = 100)
        : db_(os), buf_(buf_size) {}

    void write(const ValueType& value) {
        if (buf_pos_ == buf_.size()) flush();
        std::memcpy(&buf_[buf_pos_], &value, sizeof(ValueType));
        ++buf_pos_;
    }

    void flush() {  // could also be called in destructor?
        if (buf_pos_ != 0) {
            db_.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf_.data()), // NOLINT reincast
                      static_cast<std::streamsize>(sizeof(ValueType) * buf_pos_));
            buf_pos_ = 0;
        }
    }

  private:
    std::ostream&          db_;
    std::size_t            buf_pos_ = 0;
    std::vector<ValueType> buf_;
};

template <typename ValueType>
class flat_file_writer : public flat_file_stream_writer<ValueType> {
  public:
    explicit flat_file_writer(std::string dbfilename)
        : dbfilename_(std::move(dbfilename)), dbpath_(dbfilename_),
          ofstream_(dbpath_, std::ios::binary), flat_file_stream_writer<ValueType>(ofstream_) {
        if (!ofstream_.is_open())
            throw std::domain_error("cannot open db: " + std::string(dbpath_));
    }

  private:
    std::string                        dbfilename_;
    std::filesystem::path              dbpath_;
    std::ofstream                      ofstream_;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `std::ofstream ofstream_;` in a separate struct, then have `flat_file_writer` inherit from that struct using private. Base classes are initialized in the order they are declared, so make sure to inherit from that struct before `flat_file_stream_writer`. You can now initialize that `ofstream_` before the base class `flat_file_stream_writer`.

On closer inspection, I think you'll probably want to put all 3 of those members in the struct.

See below for updated code.

So this in effect means that the 3 members in `ofstream_holder` now come before the `flat_file_stream_writer` in the layout of `flat_file_writer`.

This seems like the right solution, not just because it "squashes the compiler warning", but because now we are really getting the correct initialization order, ie construct the std::ofstream *first* and *then* pass a reference to it to `flat_file_stream_writer`. And during destruct the `std::ofstream` will be destroyed *last*.

The original code above had this exactly the wrong way around, because the order we write in the derived constructor initializer is ignored and the actual order implemented is *layout order*, ie the order the members are declared.

(despite the flaws of the original code, it "ran fine" for me with sanitizers etc... but was probably UB?).

```cpp
template <typename ValueType>
class flat_file_stream_writer {

  public:
    explicit flat_file_stream_writer(std::ostream& os, std::size_t buf_size = 100)
        : db_(os), buf_(buf_size) {}

    void write(const ValueType& value) {
        if (buf_pos_ == buf_.size()) flush();
        std::memcpy(&buf_[buf_pos_], &value, sizeof(ValueType));
        ++buf_pos_;
    }

    void flush() {
        if (buf_pos_ != 0) {
            db_.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf_.data()), // NOLINT reincast
                      static_cast<std::streamsize>(sizeof(ValueType) * buf_pos_));
            buf_pos_ = 0;
        }
    }

  private:
    std::ostream&          db_;
    std::size_t            buf_pos_ = 0;
    std::vector<ValueType> buf_;
};

struct ofstream_holder {
    explicit ofstream_holder(std::string dbfilename)
        : dbfilename_(std::move(dbfilename)), dbpath_(dbfilename_),
          ofstream_(dbpath_, std::ios::binary) {}

    std::string           dbfilename_;
    std::filesystem::path dbpath_;
    std::ofstream         ofstream_;
};

template <typename ValueType>
class flat_file_writer : private ofstream_holder, public flat_file_stream_writer<ValueType> {
  public:
    explicit flat_file_writer(std::string dbfilename)
            : ofstream_holder(std::move(dbfilename)), flat_file_stream_writer<ValueType>(ofstream_) {
        if (!ofstream_.is_open())
            throw std::domain_error("cannot open db: " + std::string(dbpath_));
    }
};
```

Comment: *"despite the flaws of the original code, it "ran fine" for me with sanitizers"* The original code seems OK to me because `flat_file_stream_writer` constructor never actually reads from the argument, so it doesn't matter that it is uninitialized. You can still safely take a reference to it and use it later when it is properly initialized. In general, constructors tend to use the arguments that are provided to copy or move them, in which case it would have been Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OK.. fully illuminated now. Thanks